# Last known timestamp of a metric sample?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

How do I get the timestamp of the last known sample of a metric?
I want to display a table that lists when was the last time a specific service was running before it disappeared (died or whatever). The user could be looking at the table in a dashboard set with time window of say Last hour and I still want to get this timestamp displayed even if the service died 5 days ago. For the metric, I could perhaps use something like `process_start_time_seconds` or `up`, but it could be I guess any process metric as long as I get the timestamp. For example here, the last time the service existed was around 11/23. I want the table to have a column `Last Seen` and display that timestamp. There could be other rows in the table for other services.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with combination of `max_over_time()` and `timestamp()` functions, though it can pull quite a lot of historical data so be careful.

```
max_over_time( 
  timestamp(
    my_metric{my_label="somevalue"}
  )[30d:5m] # this means "repeat for each 5 minutes in 30 days range"
)
```

How it works:

1. `timestamp()` function returns the timestamp of a metric, instead of value.
2. `[30d:5m]` notation (this is called a `subquery`) makes a range of values out of previous statement.
3. `max_over_time()`, obviously, takes the maximum value out of a vector, which in case of a timestamp is like "last seen".

How long it will work (if at all) after a metric disappearance is determined by the subquery notation. If a metric disappeared before the `30d` interval - you won't see it. If a metric was a short-lived one and you set a step **larger** than `5m`, you might also miss it. `5m` step should be the minimum to catch all metrics, but it can pull a lot of data out of a large range so you might want to tweak these two.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, however when I used your example [30d:5m] looking back 30 days, it took almost 10 seconds, and after a couple of panel refreshes, Grafana crashed somehow. I changed it to [7d:] and it worked better. Actually, I'm not sure what does it mean when I made it [7d:] without specifying the second parameter.

Comment: Also, my metric was reporting several series, so I changed the query to use a max(). 
max_over_time(timestamp(max(up{pod=~"cilium-.*"}))[7d:])

Comment: @sOltan That's why I said "be careful". Also, `[7d:]` without the second parameter uses the default scrape interval, if I'm not mistaken. And that is often 30s or 60s, depends on the configuration.